# When I am using Git, should I rebase before I merge?

Tags: git, merge, github, rebase

I am working on a large scale Rails project, and the team I am working with is using Github to manage the project. While many changes are worked on locally and then pushed directly to our development branch, we create a branch when we are going to work on a very large change. When the time comes to merge that branch back into develop, I often try to rebase develop back into my feature branch before I merge my feature branch into develop (to prevent overwriting of other people's work). I find that when I do this, I seem to run into the same merge conflicts twice. I run into a whole list of conflicts while rebasing, then run into the same list of conflicts again while merging. Should I rebase develop into my feature branch before I merge my feature into develop, or should I just merge my feature into develop?

Let's say my feature branch is called "new_feature". My process for merging it with the "develop" branch goes like this:

```
git checkout develop 

git pull (this is set up on our rig to always pull rebase)

git checkout new_feature 

git rebase develop 

(lots of merge conflicts ensue) 

git checkout develop  

git merge -no-ff new_feature 

(same set of merge conflicts again)
```

It's as if the timeline changes from my rebase cause my new feature branch to kind of mirror develop all the way back, and then develop conflicts with a psudo-copy of itself.

Comment: why `git merge -no-ff`? If you just rebased new_feature onto develop, it _should_ be a fast-forward.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. For a while, we had a guy here who really knew Git, and he told me that I should do it that way for some reason that had to do with cleaning up the timeline. I don't really know what the reason was.

Comment: I can see it might make the timeline confusing ... hmm.  The rebase is replacing all the commits on `new_feature` with equivalent changes applied to `develop` instead of the original branch point, which means you'll get (copies of) old commits, whose parents (between the original branch point and `develop/HEAD`) are older than them.

Comment: I didn't rebase new_feature onto develop, did I? I thought I was rebasing develop onto new_feature.

Comment: Giant comment added as an answer - I'll try to turn it into a real answer if you can confirm I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: The reasoning behind using `--no-ff` even when the merge would be a fast-forward is that it logically groups the commits, maintaining the fact that they were in a branch at one point in the history. It is particularly useful when the branch has many commits on them and it makes sense to see that they were all part of the same feature branch as added context.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

OK, this is too long for a comment now.

To paraphrase the manual (`git help rebase`)

```
   Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "new_feature":

                 A---B---C new_feature
                /
           D---E---F---G develop


   From this point, the result of either of the following commands:

       git rebase develop
       git rebase develop new_feature

   would be:

                         A'--B'--C' <new_feature
                        /
           D---E---F---G <develop
```

Now, if you had conflicts, the actual state after first running `rebase` will be

```
              A'--B'--C'--[local state]
             /        ^
D---E---F---G          new_feature
            ^ develop
```

where `[local state]` is the conflicted merge you have yet to fix.
Once you've resolved the merge conflicts and added the resolved files to the index, you run `git rebase --continue`: now your state will be

```
              A'--B'--C'' <new_feature
             /
D---E---F---G <develop
```

(where `C''` is just `C'` after fixing conflicts).

Obviously at this point merging new_feature back onto develop can be fast-forwarded like so:

```
              A'--B'--C'' <new_feature  <develop
             /
D---E---F---G
```

but if it isn't you'll get this instead

```
              A'--B'--C'' <new_feature
             /          \
D---E---F---G------------H <develop
```

Now whichever of these you prefer from a timeline perspective, it isn't obvious why either would have a problem ... unless you never completed the rebase and resolved the conflicts with `C''`, but I would think git would complain about that.

Comment: "but if it isn't you'll get this instead"? "isn't" what? I don't understand how to cause either of these scenarios. What was the difference?

Comment: "_... can be fast-forwarded ... but if it isn't ..._". If you choose not to fast-forward the merge, with `--no-ff`, you get a merge commit instead of just moving the branch pointer, as the diagram shows. If you don't understand either scenario in the first place though, you probably need to ask your own question or otherwise learn more about git, because I can't really guess where this answer lost you.

Comment: Why would a merge commit `H` be created when you rebase?

Comment: Oh man, `H` represents any changes needed to fix up the branch after rebase, but that's not at all clear...

Answer (score 6):

Sounds to me like you are using rebase backwards but it might be just a confusing phrasing.

I'd rebase the feature branch *onto* develop and then (on develop) do a `git merge --ff-only feature`.

Comment: I'm working on editing my post to show the process, to see if I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: As @Useless commented, the merge should be a fast-forward (I prefer to force it by using the --ff-only). All the rest seems ok although your way of putting it in words is not the standard. I'd recommend reading http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 1):

1. Rebase your feature branch, merge it, done. That "rebase the feature branch before merge" in my opinion is a best practice.
2. Never rebase the develop, never modify a trunk's history (unless you and your team, you know what you are doing).
3. Rebase is just a series of cherry-picks, starting from the beginning of the branch. When you rebase develop to feature branch, you actually put all the develop commits on top of the feature branch what does not make any sense.
4. When continuing your work after merging the feature branch, just kick-off a new branch from develop and you are ready to go working on the next thing.

Comment: I think you're aiming at a linear history. IMO it doesn't necessarily better than a merge history. But yes it's better than a very convoluted history where you merge daily to catch up with the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are specifying "large-scale" and "rebase" in the same question, I would advise you to not do that. Use merges instead.

Using --no-ff in merges is great for the purpose of preserving the original branch point. I support using it.

Comment: Claiming that "large-scale" and "rebase" are mutually inappropriate is incorrect. No matter how big the project is, when working with feature branches, rebasing them before merging is actually a best practice. What is wrong, are these attempts to rebase develop used by a team, what is a bad practice no matter the size of the project (in the vast majority of cases).